# What if I store 10TB on azure servers and then keep the vm powered off?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, hard-drive, storage

I want to know should I pay for storage on azure even if I don't use it?
for example if I store 10TB on an azure VM and then keep that VM powered off, Will Microsoft charge me for that 10TB data? Or it just charges us for powered on VMs?

Comment: If you just need some data stored, look at AWS S3, or whatever the matching Azure offering is.  No server needed that way.

Comment: For storage only Backblaze and Wasabi might be a better options. They both are built around storage charges, rather than AWS / Azure who’re about compute primary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you’ll be charged for persistent storage. No, you won’t be charged for anything on a temp disk, but your data won’t survive a reboot. System disk written “extras” will be added to your “storage” bill.

Comment: Data on *system* disks will always survive a reboot; it's data on *temporary* disks that doesn't.

Comment: It's not cheap either, way more than gcloud, and more than AWS. It is still worth shutting down the VM's though. The level of granularity in the cost explorer leaves a lot to be desired too, but they are improving.

Answer (score 11):

Questions about products or services pricing are off topic here.

Anyway, yes, you will pay for used storage space even when no one is actively accessing it; the actual price depends on the type and size of the storage. More info here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/page-blobs/